# Error message "Data Studio isn't available at the moment" for days

Tags: looker-studio

Some of our reports suddenly produce the following error message when trying to open them (from https://datastudio.google.com/)

> We're sorry! Data Studio isn't available at the moment. Please try again later.

We are getting this message for more than 24h now. Any idea what the reason might be, and how to regain access to the reports?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the issue on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test out the issue. Without a Reproducible Example it would be difficult to pinpoint exactly where the issue lies, e.g. the Data Set, the Data Source, the report, a temporary outage, etc

Comment: No, I cannot, unfortunately. The reports turned from perfectly working into a state where they couldn't even be loaded, without us doing anything. The goal of this question was to get any hints as to what might trigger this. Turns out, it's very likely something on Google's end (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70404237/7746472).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While I still don't know what the root cause was, it's very likely something outside our sphere of influence. Looks like someone on Google's side pushed the wrong button, as it affected more users than just us (see, e.g., [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/138562038/data-studio-not-available-right-now-try-again-later) and [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/138504851/data-studio-is-not-available-right-now)).

So to fix this, have a look at the Google support forums, and then sit back, relax, and hope that Google is quick to do their thing.